# How to read a file and write in to another file using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which looks like this (file1.txt)

```
258.2222
```

I have to write this `file1.txt` value to another file. if there in no value (empty) in `file1.txt` then
it should print as "Passed".

this is what I tried

```
for final in $(cat file1.txt);do
if [ "$final" ];then
        echo $final  > file2.txt
else
        echo "Passed" > file2.txt
fi
done
```

this only works with 1 scenario. if there is no value in `file1.txt` then it is not writing as **"Passed"**

expected output:

if there is a value in `file1.txt`:

```
258.2222
```

if there is no value(empty) in `file1.txt`:

```
Passed
```

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

Note: I am not allowed to use general purpose scripting language (JavaScript, Python etc).

Comment: Can there be more than one line in the file?

Comment: No. only one line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73864629/how-to-read-a-file-and-write-in-to-another-file-using-a-shell-script   Please do not post the same question on different sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is the `for` loop. When you have no value in the file, there is nothing for the `for` loop to iterate over, so it doesn't even start and, therefore, the `if` is never evaluated. However, since there can only ever be one line in the file, there's no point in looping anyway. Just do something like this:

```bash
final=$(cat file1.txt)
if [ -n "$final" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$final" 
else
    printf 'Passed\n'
fi
```

Then, run the script and redirect its output to a file (it is generally bad practice to hard code the output file name since that can result in unintentionally overwriting any existing file with the same name and also limits how the script can be used):

```
script.sh > file2.txt
```

Note that this will also print if the file has nothing but spaces, since that is "something" and not "nothing".

Answer (score 0):

If `file1.txt` contains something (its file size is non-zero), you want that something to go into `file2.txt`:

```bash
if [ -s file1.txt ]; then
    cp file1.txt file2.txt
fi
```

If `file1.txt` is *empty* (or missing), then you want a line saying `Passed` written to `file2.txt`:

```bash
if [ -s file1.txt ]; then
    cp file1.txt file2.txt
else
    echo Passed >file2.txt
fi
```

If you want to avoid creating `file2.txt` if `file1.txt` is missing:

```bash
if [ -s file1.txt ]; then
    cp file1.txt file2.txt
elif [ -e file1.txt ]; then
    echo Passed >file2.txt
fi
```

The `echo` is now only executed if the `-s` test fails (the file does not exist, or it is empty) and `-e` test succeeds (the file exists).

At no point do you actually have to read the data from the file in a loop.